# mySQL Trigger update count

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to set up a trigger in mySQL so that when a new team is added,deleted or updated  it triggers an update in countTeams and changes the base count and countNA etc to the corresponding nationality of the team.

Here's my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE countTeams(
    base integer PRIMARY KEY,
    countNA integer,
    countEU integer,
    countCN integer,
    countSEA integer,
    countINT integer,
    countCIS integer
    );
CREATE TABLE Team(
    TeamName varchar (30) PRIMARY KEY,
    Captain varchar (30),
    Nationality varchar (5) NOT NULL,
    CreationDate date,
    Description varchar (50),
    foreign key(Captain) references Emails(Username)
    );
```

My failed trigger attempt.

```
CREATE TRIGGER teamsDown
AFTER INSERT ON Team FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE countTeams
BEGIN
SET base = (base - 1)
IF Team.Nationality= "NA" THEN
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countNA = (countNA - 1)
ELSEIF Team.Nationality = "EU" THEN
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countEU = (countEU - 1)
IF Team.Nationality = "CN" THEN
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countCN = (countCN - 1)
IF Team.Nationality = "SEA"
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countSEA = (countSEA - 1)
IF Team.Nationality = "INT"
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countINT = (countINT - 1)
IF Team.Nationality = "CIS"
    UPDATE countTeams
    SET countCIS = (countCIS - 1)
END;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, change your countTeams table.

```
CREATE TABLE countTeams(
    base int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nationality varchar(5),
    how_many int DEFAULT 0
);
```

Then fill it with needed data.

```
INSERT INTO countTeams (nationality) VALUES
('NA'),
('EU'),
('CN'),
('SEA'),
('INT'),
('CIS');
```

Now you have to create a trigger for insert and one for delete. Update doesn't change anything, not sure why you want to create a trigger for this. Or can the nationality of a team change afterwards?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_countTeams AFTER INSERT ON Team
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE countTeams SET how_many = how_many + 1 WHERE nationality = NEW.nationality;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER dec_countTeams AFTER DELETE ON Team
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE countTeams SET how_many = how_many - 1 WHERE nationality = OLD.nationality;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER dec_countTeams AFTER UPDATE ON Team
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE countTeams SET how_many = how_many - 1 WHERE nationality = OLD.nationality;
  UPDATE countTeams SET how_many = how_many + 1 WHERE nationality = NEW.nationality;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, and yeah the nationality of a team can change afterwards.